# Android UIAutomator empty view group

Tags: android, android-uiautomator, uiautomatorviewer

as you can see in my screen capture, when I'm navigating in the uiautomator tree when I have items with a lot of depth I see empty view groups, but in reality this view groups have content inside.

I tried with other apps like youtube and I have the same issue.

Also I tested doing this research programmatically using JUnit test and I have the same issue.

Thank you so much in advance for your help.

[image]